# Getting an image with the ASHX extension

Tags: php

I am crawling some websites for images. However, some of these sites have the `.ashx` extension, which makes me unable to determine the sizes of the images.

I am using `getimagesize()`:

```
$imgsize = getimagesize($url);
```

This results in the following error:

```
getimagesize(url): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How can I get around this, and check the size of the image?

Comment: do those 'images' actually return an image (jpg/png/gif) when visited, or are they similar to 1x1 tracking pixels?

Comment: When going to the URL in the browser, it shows an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can attempt to use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971333/697370), although I think it should work the way you have it already:

```
// From @dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971333/697370
$cont = file_get_contents($url);
$r = imagecreatefromstring($cont);
imagesx($r);
imagerx($r);
```

Your original code may not be working if:

1. You don't have `allow_url_fopen` enabled (unlikely as I think that would also cause you to not be able to fetch regular images with `getimagesize()`), or
2. The .ashx script is correctly generating an image, but is not sending the correct headers which is causing `getimagesize` to fail.

There may be other causes, but those are the only two I can think of.